# How to list options of a service

Tags: linux, command-line, centos, services

On CentOS, there is a service which we normally run `service acme_donkey start registry` I would like to find out if there are any options to this service, such debug, etc.  Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends on the service. In most cases you have to look in /etc/init.d/ and read the file named after the service (/etc/init.d/acme_donkey in your case).

This is valid for CentOS < 7.0